# Criminal penalties in Portuguese law for rape?

Tags: child-abuse, rape, sentencing, portugal

How long or short of a prison sentence can one get in Portugal for rape or domestic abuse?

Answer (score 3):

The maximum sentence for any offense in Portugal is 25 years under Article 41 of the [Penal Code of Portugal](https://www.legislationline.org/download/id/4288/file/Portugal_CC_2006_en.pdf) (PCC).

[Article 152](http://europam.eu/data/mechanisms/PF/PF%20Laws/Portugal/Portugal_criminal%20code_1982_amended2015_por.pdf) of the PCC provides that domestic violence is punishable by up to 5 years in prison.

[Articles 163-174](http://europam.eu/data/mechanisms/PF/PF%20Laws/Portugal/Portugal_criminal%20code_1982_amended2015_por.pdf) of the PCC set forth penalties for a variety of sex offenses (incidentally, "rapto" is a false friend in Portuguese which looked like "rape" in English but means "kidnapping" or more literally "abduction" in Portuguese). The most severe penalty available for any of these sex offenses (assuming it is not a  aggravating factor of another crime with a more severe penalty like murder or kidnapping) is six years in prison. Most sex offenses in Portugal are punishable by not more than five years in prison.

There are punishments in addition to imprisonment that can be imposed in many cases, but the question asks only about prison sentences.

The minimum sentences are not meaningful because alternative sentencing options exist.

Comment: What about minimum sentences, for domestic abuse, and for abduction?